# Unzipping downloaded artifacts + dependency list

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

We use `maven-dependency-plugin` to download ZIP artifacts from our repository in Nexus and then unzip them. The corresponding command in `pom.xml` is like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-zip-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.ourdomain</groupId>
                                <artifactId>our-item</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.0</version>
                                <classifier>bin</classifier>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <outputDirectory>./ourfolder</outputDirectory>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
```

Everything works perfectly.

Nevertheless, we'missing one thing: when we create a site for the artifact (command `mvn site`) the downloaded and unzipped artifacts don't appear under `Dependencies` because the corresponding entries in `pom.xml`'s `<dependencies>` section are missing. Of course we can make the entries but they are REDUNDANT to those made above. Having dozens of artifacts it's pretty lot.

Is there any possibility to solve this problem in an 'elegant' way?

Comment: Why are you unpack them into a folder? What kind of project do you have a war, ear ?

Comment: These are general projects storing ZIP files.